# Boost.Python import module causes SegFault

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

Trying to create a boost.python shared library and am getting this:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()
>>> import alucard
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f575e14f740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 34 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 25 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72 in apport_excepthook
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I resolve this issue or find more information on how to resolve the segfault? My actual source code is pretty big and would be impossible to post here, dont think it would help either.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is this error happenning right when importing module from Python (module made in C++)? Have you tried putting some `std::cout` printing in the very first lines of C++ module code? This will help to figure out which lines of C++ code are causing crash. You can put some debug printing around each line of C++ e.g. `std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;`. So that you narrow down lines that causing segfault. Also nice to make very small C++ module first, but which works 100%. Then to add extra code till it starts crashing.

Comment: This is occuring right at the `import alucard` which is a C++ shared library. I can place some `couts` for debugging but im not sure how much that will help. I tried loading the module with eclipse and it produced the error: `ImportError: /home/jlahowetz2/development/cpp-python-wrapper/build/pbuilder.so: undefined symbol: c2_`... Im not sure what symbol this is though

Comment: Anyway one of the most important steps of debugging a problem in any program is to localize the problem, meaning that you need to find lines in a C++ code that crash. After such lines are found it is usually much easier to find the bug and fix it.